# Parsing JSON data in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have encountered a bizarre case when attempting to parse some JSON data sent from a server.

The data is essentially, a set of rows of data - i.e. a list of lists, and looks something like this:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

In FF (using Firebug), the received JSON data is valid, and renders correctly.

When I attempt to parse the JSON data using either of this statements, it fails:

1. `JSON.parse()`
   code breaks on error
2. `jQuery.parseJSON()`
   parses without complaining, yet the result of the parse is a null object

The only way I have managed to successfully parse the JSON response, is to use the dreaded `eval()` statements, which is a BIG security issue.

Anyone knows what may be going on?

Comment: Testing it in Firebug gives no problems: `>>> JSON.parse("[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]"); [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]`. I suspect that you have over-reduced your reduced test case.

Comment: What does jslint say? Did you check whitespace? Any invalid (invisible) characters? Encoding OK?

Comment: $.parseJSON() actually uses eval() after cleaning checking the JSON string with regex.

Comment: why don't you use eval('(' + dataString + ')') what is the security issue for that. I've used this method every time, and it works fine

Comment: I found the solution. It seems that when the server responds with a content type of text/json, the string is automatially parsed by jQuery into a JSO object, so I was ineffect trying to parse twice - hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just starting my adventure with JavaScript and JSON, but it looks like it's not a valid JSON object. There is no key:value in this list of lists. I wold suggest changing it into list of obects containing list fields. Sth like:

```
[ 
{ list: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
{ list: [ 1, 2, 3 ] },
{ list: [ 1, 2, 3 ] }
]
```

But I might be very wrong.

Comment: You are indeed very wrong. No need for keys, it's perfectly valid, see David's comment.

Comment: There are no "lists". There are arrays and objects. While you can have an array of objects, nothing prevents you having an array of arrays.

Comment: Thx! You posted your comment, while I was replaying - I saw it afterwards. Actually it's quite obvious - I don't know were my mind was.